# Xsl-Fo How to fix multiple template call caused by grouping?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have the problem, that when i use `for-each-group` and `for-each select="current-group()"` in combination with `apply-templates select="."` that the same templates ist called twice for the same element what causes double definition of a generated id.

my xml is something like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <report>
        <reportelements>
            <section name="1 section">
                <pagemaster>DIN-A4-PREFACE</pagemaster>
                <reportelements>
                    <picture name="1.1 picture">
                        <pagemaster>TITLEPAGE</pagemaster>
                        <reportelements />
                    </picture>
                    <section name="1.2 section">
                        <pagemaster>DIN-A4-PREFACE</pagemaster>
                        <subtitlecontent />
                        <reportelements>
                            <paragraph name="1.2.1 paragraph">
                                <pagemaster>TITLEPAGE</pagemaster>
                                <reportelements />
                            </paragraph>
                            <paragraph name="1.2.2 paragraph">
                                <pagemaster>DIN-A4-PREFACE</pagemaster>
                                <reportelements />
                            </paragraph>
```

My problematic xsl call is

```xml
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//reportelements/*[pagemaster != '']" group-adjacent="pagemaster">

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </fo:flow>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:page-sequence>

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The problem here is that the apply templates is once called for the group

```
-1 section
  -1.1 picture
  -1.2 section
    -1.2.1 paragraph
    -1.2.2 paragraph
```

and then again for:

```
-1.2 section
    -1.2.1 paragraph
    -1.2.2 paragraph
```

So there is a `block id="{generate-id(.)}"` in the template for the 1.2 section that gets called twice and causes an error when generating pdf.

What I want is that the apply Templates gets called individually for each element without calling it for the children.

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your code for us to see where the bug is. If you don't want the template rule for an element to recurse to the children, write a template rule that doesn't call apply-templates.

Comment: Is the issue that you have a duplicated ID or that you have a complete second copy of the processed section in your result?

Comment: This question is not clear. You are grouping and then iterating over each member of groups in turn. That doesn't show a flow with a template instantiated twice.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want same variation on:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except section" />
```

where you select all of the child nodes *except* the ones that are not going to be in the current group.

Strictly speaking, you want something that tests for membership of the current group, e.g. (untested):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[. &lt;&lt; current-group()[last()]],
                             current-group()[last()]" />
```